# Using Entity Framework on a database with no foreign keys - how to 'fake' them?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

At my current job I am endlessly plagued by a series of decisions made by my predecessor that culminate in:

1. All Primary Keys are Guids (not a bad thing by itself)
2. There are **no foreign keys** in the database (this is handled by the business logic)
3. When a 'foreign key' is empty, instead of `null` we use `Guid.Empty`. The fields are all nullable, but mountains of business logic and reports rely on empty fields being `Guid.Empty`

I have been wracking my brain for the longest time to try and add some sanity to this model. The thoughts I've had are

1. Can't just add foreign keys to the database. This would immediately break tons of functionality and isn't feasible.
2. We've been migrating to use Entity Framework lately. I've read about mocking up EF Models so that you have fake, in code foreign keys, but this is defeated by all of the Empty Guids in the database and would generate a key not found error
3. I've considered adding 'empty' records to each of the tables so the empty Guids have something to point to, but that gives us an extra blank row on everything (like when displaying a list), and breaks reports that apparently rely on certain queries for empty guid returning nothing.
4. My only vaguely functional thought was that I could modify parts of Entity Framework to handle Empty Guids with special rules, but this fills me with thoughts of sadness, not to mention it's outside of my capabilities to do this reliably.

I would really REALLY love to be able to at least use Entity Framework's lazy loading and `Include` capabilities to get associated records, but I can't think of a way this is possible given our current database schema/model. Does anyone have any suggestions/thoughts?

Comment: if there is no  foreign keys, how can you relate tables between them ?

Comment: @BilelChaouadi the relationships exist, the keys themselves just aren't in nor enforced in the database. They exist in our `minds`

Comment: in this case, you can just use the virtual keyword to allow the lazy loading

Comment: Can you show us some code and the error you get when you access a navigation property or use include when the foreign key contains an empty guid?

Answer (score -1):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb738488%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should help you out to get started, this will help you out to map the relations yourself in the designer.

Comment: Entity Framework requires the database schema have foreign keys for any relations you map.